# How to convert multiple columns value as header for set of values in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:(SQL Server)

tableA

```
  +-----------+--------+--------------+----------+
  | tableA_id |  code  | Department   |  Column1 |
  +-----------+--------+--------------+----------+
  |         1 | code A | Science 1    |  NULL    |
  |         2 | code B | Science 1    |  Test    |
  |         3 | code A | Science 2    |  Null    |
  |         4 | code C | Science 1    |  Test1   |
  |         5 | code B | Science 2    |  Test    |
  |         6 | code A | Science 3    |  NULL    |
  |         7 | code C | Science 2    |  Test1   |
  |         8 | code B | Science 3    |  Test    |
  |         9 | code A | Science 4    |  NULL    |
  |        10 | code C | Science 3    |  Test1   |
  |        11 | code B | Science 4    |  Test    |
  +-----------+--------+--------------+----------+
```

I want to convert in below format -

```
 +--------------+ 
 | Department   |
 +--------------+
 | Code A NULL  |
 +--------------+
 |  Science 1   |
 |  Science 2   |
 |  Science 3   |
 |  Science 4   |
 +--------------+ 
 |  Code B Test |
 +--------------+
 | Science 1    |
 | Science 2    |
 | Science 3    |
 | Science 4    |
 +--------------+
 |  Code C Test1|
 +--------------+
 | Science 1    |
 | Science 2    |
 | Science 3    |
 +--------------+
```

Basically i want it group by Code and Column1 but need to display Code and Column1 at top of each group and values in column not fixed it comes dynamically.

I used below query for Code column as below -

```
select coalesce(A.department, A.code) as 'Department'
from TableA A
group by A.code, A.department with rollup
having grouping(A.code) = 0
order by A.code, A.department;
```

But when i trying same query for Code and Column1, it is not giving expected result -

```
select coalesce(A.department, A.code,A.Column1) as 'Department'
from TableA A
group by A.code, A.department,A.Column1 with rollup
having grouping(A.code) = 0 and grouping(A.Column1)=0
order by A.code, A.department,A.Column1;
```

Comment: This requirement would honestly best be handled in your presentation layer, e.g. something like PHP or Java.  Do you require this exact output directly from SSMS?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes i require it in SSMS, because in my presentation layer it is not allowing me to do it. I am not using PHP or java or .net code

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach which brings in the sub headers via a union query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        code, Column1, code + ' ' + COALESCE(Column1, 'NULL') AS Department, 1 AS priority
    FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT code, Column1, Department, 2 FROM tableA
)

SELECT Department
FROM cte
ORDER BY code, Column1, Department, priority;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: How to add column next to Department in same query?

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Can you be more clear?

Comment: I updated table with extra column, i need output in this format. Can you please help me in that.

Comment: Just add the second column to the select clause of the CTE, and then select it out.